# Multiply values based on numerous criteria

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, excel-2007

I have two sheets: http://s4.postimg.org/aryzvl13v/Capture.png < image of the two tables.

I have to find the `sell price` in the first table. In order to do this I need to match the `type`. After that, I check if the `cost` is more than column B in the second table. Then I'd find the multiplier for the corresponding cost. Once I find the right multiplier, then I can find the `Sell Price` which equals the `Cost` x `Multiplier`.

So I need a formula for Column D that matches the `type`, then finds the biggest possible "If Cost is more than", and finally multiplies the corresponding multiplier with the cost.

For example: let's say I have item `467874` of type: `PKG` and a cost of `$8.45`. Because it's more than $3.00 but less than $10.00, I would use the multiplier `1.85`.

> So the Sell Price for `467874` would be `8.45` x `1.85` = $15.63

I need to be able to change Sheet2 later, so the formula would have to be dynamic. Otherwise I would just use "IF" statements. So I want to be able to add and delete fields onto Sheet2.

Comment: You're right, I should have added a 0 for each "type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a changed lookup array in Sheet2:

[image: SO30652011 example]

I suggest:

```
=ROUND(C2*IF(B2="PKG",INDEX(Sheet2!C$2:C$7,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!B$2:B$7,1)),IF(B2="POPULAR",INDEX(Sheet2!C$8:C$11,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!B$8:B$11,1)),INDEX(Sheet2!C$12:C$14,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!B$12:B$14,1)))),2)
```

in D2 copied down to suit.

Comment: Thank you so much @pnuts. But I made the mistake of not adding that I need Sheet2 to be dynamic. In other words, I would need to be able to add and delete rows later on.